# Jquery same function on several elements

Tags: jquery, var

I have this code that opens popups when clicked on an element:

```
$("#isl2").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht_2").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_2").scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});

$("#isl3").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht_2").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_3").scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});

$("#isl4").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht_4").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_4").scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});

$("#isl5").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht_5").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_5").scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});

$("#isl6").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht_6").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_6").scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});

$("#isl7").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht_7").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_7").scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});
```

Now I know that this is probably too much code for such a simple function so I'm trying to make it smaller. I probably have to use a var but that's where my js knowledge ends. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use a class with all the elements and get the number from their id.

Answer (score 1):

You may define a class for all objects and define the function on `class` not on `ID` but find the desired ID using element ID or its data attribute:

```
<a class="clickable" data-id="18">Number 18</a>
<a class="clickable" data-id="19">Number 19</a>
<a class="clickable" data-id="20">Number 20</a>
```

script:

```
$(".clickable").click(function () {
    var id= $(this).data("id");
    $("#opdracht_"+ id).slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_"+ id).scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});
```

If you don't want to modify your curent HTML this is the ugly way to solve it (ugly because you may have other class starting with name `isl`):

```
$("[id^=isl]").click(function () {
    var id= this.id.replace("isl","");
    $("#opdracht_"+ id).slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_"+ id).scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had classes on those elements so your first suggestion works flawlessly, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You could combine all the selectors into one and parse the `id` for the numeric value that is different. Then use that to concatenate the other 2 selectors

Using a common class for the elements with those ids would make the initial selectors simpler.

```
$("#isl2, #isl3, #isl4, #isl5, #isl6, #isl7").click(function () {
     var num = this.id.replace('isl', '');

    $("#opdracht_" + num).slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    $(".opdracht_title_" + num).scramble( 1000, 10000 );
});
```